# how to save AJAX RESPONSE in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, save, response

```
   return Response()->json(['message' => $input['first_name']]);
```

give me in console my input text How can i save it in database?

I try to use

```
$input = Request::all();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->first_name = Response()->json(['message' => $input['first_name']]);
        $user->save();
```

but dont work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be confused with the response()..
That Response()... is what should be RETURNED in the end of the controller. That example would be

```
    $input = Request::all();
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->first_name = $input->first_name;
    $user->save();
    return response()->json(['user_saved' => $user ]);
```

EDIT

```
// HomeController.php
public function editUser(Request $request){
  $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->first();
  $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
  if($user->save()){
    return response()->json(["response" =>true,"user"=>$user]);
  }
  return response()->json(["response" =>false,"user"=>$user]);
}

// routes/web.php
 Route::post('/user/update',[
  'uses'=>'HomeController@editUser',
  'as'=>'editUser'
 ]);

// javascript 
$('#updateProfile').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '{{route("editUser")}}',
    data: { first_name: $('#firstname').val(), _token: token }
})
```

(NOTE if you're using .js files, you might want to on your **.blade.php including the .js file, define the variable url there like you seem to be doing with token
For example in blade)
    // index.blade.php

```
<script>
  var token = "{{Session::token()}}";
  var urlEditUser = '{{route("editUser")}}';
</script>
```

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/home/user/update 500 (Internal Server Error)
What now?

Comment: Same, i want to update data user, without refresh page.
He click a "Save" and alert done or no.

I know how to do that with refresh, he go to /home/user/update and work
But i dont know how to without refresh

Comment: return Response()->json(['message' => $input['first_name']]); returned my name in console, so this work, but hove to save it using $user->first_name?

Comment: the Response()->json(['message' => $input['first_name']]); is only used at the end. it is what returns to the browser, to edit the model you need to first apply the value in $input['first_name'] to $user ( the user object) then, save the user using $user->save() and then you do the return in the end if everything goes well

Comment: Can you give me example? I'm sorry but i dont know how to do that. Thanks bro ♥

Comment: $user->first_name = $input['first_name'];
$user->save();
return response()->json(["user"=>$user]);

Comment: can you see my post?

Comment: Edited once again with full example

Comment: This work bro! But now how can i echo popup "DONE" if user change data?

Comment: $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '{{route("editUser")}}',
    data: { first_name: $('#firstname').val(), _token: token }
}),success: function( result ) {
        console.log(result);
        alert(result .response);

Answer (score 0):

i send the data like that:

`$('#updateProfile').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/home/user/update',
        data: { first_name: $('#firstname').val(), _token: token }
    })`

you example dont work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->first_name = request('first_name');
$user->save();

return response()->json([ 'user_saved' => $user ]);
```

Comment: But now how can i echo popup "DONE" if data has changed?